# Cannot precompile assets on amazon server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am working with rails app. this app is deployed on amazon I am trying to precompile assets it throws an error

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /public/assets/application-23fe644956af6dcd73aee2d2f3e24295.js
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide more details? You have not really given enough information to be able to answer. What are you trying to do? How are you trying to do that? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? Be specific.

Comment: I am trying to precompile assets on server RAILS_ENV=staging rake assets:precompile so this command throws an error Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /public/assets/application-23fe644956af6dcd73aee2d2f3e24295.js

Comment: ok thanks for providing the command, but I meant please provide _new_ information because what you gave in your question was not enough. Are you running on EC2? What user are you running as? Ubuntu or AmazonLinux? What version of Ruby/Rails? Do you have administrator access? How is it deployed? Please edit your question so readers can easily understand without having to parse through comments.

Comment: i am a newbie yes i am using EC2 and user is ubuntu. ruby version is 2.2.4 and rails 4.2, i dont have other informations. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your user does not have permission to write to `/public/assets`.

Its hard to know exactly how things are setup on your system, but you could probably get it to work by taking ownership of the folder with `sudo` (but always use caution with `sudo` as you can mess up your system if you don't know what you're doing):

```
sudo chown ubuntu /public/assets
```